# Jquery Theme Reload

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I've changed my jquery theme but when I try to open website into my browser then it loads old theme. I have checked with CTRL + R, CTRL + F5 and also restarted browser. Its loading old theme again. I've also tried with CHROMe but same problem. But When I open this website on another computer where I haven't opened it before then it loads new theme. I've tried to add following meta tags but not succeeded. Any advice please.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="expires" CONTENT="0">
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Clear your browser cache then. If you can open the new theme on other computer it is your compurre fault, is not it?

Comment: I've just renamed folder on server and refreshed the page and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should just clear the cache used on the browser of your computer. It can be viewed right in other computer simply because the browser in those computer still has no cache of the old theme.

Comment: I've just renamed folder on server and refreshed the page and it worked